# log4j:WARN No such property [conversionPattern] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, hibernate

Can someone help me with this error message. I don't know why my application is always showing these warning

```
log4j:WARN No such property [conversionPattern] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
```

My application is a simple hibernate project

**Here is the complete properties file**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# Direct log messages to a log file  
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=logs/HibernateAnnotation.log 
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n 

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting  
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=warn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> log4j.appender.A1.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

It should be `log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern` and not `log4j.appender.A1.ConversionPattern1`.