# Log4j is not reading capitalized letters

Tags: java, html, layout, log4j

I'm experiencing this issue using Log4j:

> log4j:WARN No such property [conversionPattern] in org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout.

I've searched and changed the name of every mention of the property from conversionPattern to ConversionPattern. But apparently log4j is unable to recognize the capitalized letter.

I have followed the instructions stated in this link, but the error still persists.

https://coderanch.com/t/64013/open-source/log-properties-insanity

Here's my log4j.properties

```
# Define the types of logger and level of logging    
#log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG,console, FILE

# Define the File appender    
/*log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender    

# Define Console Appender    
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender    

# Define the layout for console appender. If you do not 
# define it, you will get an error    
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Set the name of the file    
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.log

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)    
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode    
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite    
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender    
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout    
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n*/



# Define the root logger with appender file
#log = log
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log/htmlLayout.html
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.Title=HTML Layout Example
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.LocationInfo=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Can you post the log4j.properties file for more clarity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j:WARN No such property \[conversionPattern\] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130692/log4jwarn-no-such-property-conversionpattern-in-org-apache-log4j-rollingfilea)

Comment: I don't think is a duplicate. In that thread they solve the issue by using ConversionPattern instead of ConversionPattern1. In my case I am already using ConversionPattern but log4j does not detect the capitalized